# How to generate but exclude a certain number in a certain digit integer in python

Tags: python, random

I am just wondering on how to generate a certain digit integer, but also excluding a certain digit from appearing in that number.

For example, if I were to exclude the digit 0 on a 3 digit number, there won't be any 0's appearing no matter how many times I generate it. Examples of outcomes would be 591, 292, 182, 111, 181, 738, etc.

If this were to be in a function, e.g

```
def randomIntWithNDigits(n):
```

, it would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Did you try writing it?

Comment: cannot do that directly, best approach would be to generate randoms while a matching random [one without a 3 in it] appears

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution, using random choice of characters in a string, which contains every digit except the digits you don't want.

```
import random

def randomIntWithNDigits(n):
    numbers = '12456789'
    result = ''
    for i in range(0,n):
        result+= random.choice(numbers)
    return result
```

Comment: `''.join(random.choice(numbers) for i in range(n))`

Answer (score 0):

That's quite easy. For example, with 0 excluded:

```
def randomIntWithNDigits(n):
    allowedDigits = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    randInts = []
    for i in range(n):
        randInts.append(random.sample(allowedDigits, 1))
    return int(''.join(map(str, randInts)))
```

When needed to exclude some other digits you should just change allowedDigits.

Answer (score -1):

```
import random

def generaterandom(n):
    while True:
        rand = random.randrange(0,n)
        if not '3' in rand.__str__():
            return rand;

print generaterandom(10)
```